# Python, implementing proxy support for a socket based application (not urllib2)

Tags: python, proxy, tcp, sockets, socks

I am little stumped: I have a simple messenger client program (pure python, sockets), and I wanted to add proxy support (http/s, socks), however I am a little confused on how to go about it. I am assuming that the connection on the socket level will be done to the proxy server, at which point the headers should contain a CONNECT + destination IP (of the chat server) and authentication, (if proxy requires so), however the rest is a little beyond me. How is the subsequent connection handled, specifically the reading/writing, etc...

Are there any guides on proxy support implementation for socket based (tcp) programming in Python?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use something like [SocksiPy](http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/) which does all the protocol details for you and would let you connect through a SOCKS proxy as you would without it?

Comment: This works well. I was able to integrate everything, and the code of SocksiPy shows exactly what happens during the tunneling of HTTP/SOCKS. I am very surprised I have not found it before, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple - after you send the HTTP request: `CONNECT example.com:1234 HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: example.com:1234\r\n<additional headers incl. authentication>\r\n\r\n`, the server responds with `HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n` and then (after the double line ends) you can communicate just as you would communicate with example.com port 1234 without the proxy (as I understand you already have the client-server communication part done).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, much appreciated. I had to accept the previous poster though, because I was able to integrate his solution quite easily and the code even demonstrates SOCKS4/5 handling, in addition to the HTTP tunneling.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/).

> Stunnel can allow you to secure
>   non-SSL aware daemons and protocols
>   (like POP, IMAP, LDAP, etc) by having
>   Stunnel provide the encryption,
>   requiring no changes to the daemon's
>   code